# a:active vs mousedown event preventDefault()-ed

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, cross-browser, css-selectors

### The case

- we have an `<a>` element with `:active` state specified in CSS
- in JavaScript code we listen to `mousedown` event and call `event.preventDefault()` for some reasons :)
- As a result: in **Firefox** when I move mouse cursor over the anchor and click it -- anchor is not displayed as `:active`
- I have also tested this issue in some Chrome / Opera / IE versions -- all that browsers had decorated the anchor as if it was `:active`.

Here is a test for the case:
http://jsbin.com/azajex/4

### The question

On W3C there is not deep description, what must be considered `active` and when.

But all browsers (maybe, not all?) except FF handle mousedown firstly by CSS engine and render the element as `:active`. It appears to be a long time issue, I tested this case in FF 3.6, 8.0, 13.0 -- all that versions behave exactly the same.

**So, what is the right behaviour of a browser in this case?**

Comment: Just a note, when you click it it is red, but it does not stay red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'correct behavior'. It is up to browser implementations and should not be relied upon. This is known as [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In software engineering, undefined behaviors should be not be relied upon as it has no true documentation nor are the results verifiable.

> CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states [pseudo-classes: :hover, :active, and :focus], or how the states are entered and left. Scripting may change whether elements react to user events or not, and different devices and UAs[browsers] may have different ways of pointing to, or activating elements. 
>   -[W3C CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

Comment: Yes. A common misconception among web developers is that `:hover`, `:active`, and `:focus` are the direct CSS correspondents to their respective JavaScript events, and thus they should work hand-in-hand in both languages. This is simply not true. It just happens *by coincidence* that not only does CSS define an `:active` pseudo-class which *may* apply when the mouse is down on an element, but JavaScript also has `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. In no way does that imply that the pseudo-class state depends on the events or that the events depend on or trigger the pseudo-class state.

Comment: @andrew-martinez: I have read the w3c but I have missed this part. Thank you for pointing that out.