# Prevent label active state using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a quite [simple scenario](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPZVrO) where I am trying to prevent the orange background on mouse down:

```js
document.querySelector('label').addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  console.log('mouse down') 
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
label:active {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<label>Press mouse down</label>
```

Unfortunately the `event.preventDefault()` has no effect and the label becomes orange. (Tested in Chrome and Safari and IE11)

[image: Label Bug Demo]

Can anyone explain me the reason behind that or maybe tell me how to prevent the active state programatically without hacks?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPZVrO

Comment: works fine in FF.

Comment: Oh okay I'll update the question in this case - thanks @techLove

Comment: @Christoph Check out my edit/rollback comment - the `console.log(event)` causes major issues when combined with SO snippet's console output.

Comment: Haha, what a mess we made ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure about this and have no source to back it up, but I think `preventDefault` cancels the *actions* (e.g. following the link, or submitting a form), but not the state! I would say, FF's behaviour is wrong here.

Comment: @jantimon I hope you don't mind, but I've commented out the `console.log()` portion of your snippet. It's simply too much output for SO's snippet output to handle, causes major lock-ups. **EDIT:** Nevermind, you seem to have re-added it.

Comment: @Santi thanks I added it back in :D

Answer (score 5):

[It seems like an old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11464520/1542290). If you want, you can fix it, by using `pointer-events` property. Also, [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) for the same is pretty much decent (including IE11)

```css
label:active {
  background: orange;
}

label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Press mouse down</label>
```

Make sure you have some `class` or an `id` declared on the `label` element so that you don't target all of them.

---

**JavaScript Solution** - Just giving a shot

The idea is to add a `class` on `mousedown` and override it with CSS `class` having an `:active` pseudo `class`, and later, remove the `class` on `mouseup` .. something like

```js
var overrideActive = function() {
  var labelElm = document.querySelector('label');
  var bodyElm = document.querySelector('body');

  function init() {
    //on mousedown, add a class and override it with css
    labelElm.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
      event.target.className = 'disable-active';
    });

    //onmouseout get rid of the class
    bodyElm.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
      labelElm.classList.remove('disable-active');
    });
  }

  return {
    init: init
  }
}();

overrideActive.init();
```

```css
label:active {
  background: orange;
}

.disable-active:active {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<label>Press mouse down</label>
```

Comment: Well I don't want to prevent it in every case that's why I am trying to do it using javascript (like in the title of the question)

Comment: @jantimon using `mousedown` and `e.preventDefault()` is going to prevent it anyways.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say - in the real app I would add an `if` ;)

Comment: The real problem is that it completely ignores the element for pointer events. This causes: a) the behaviour of the UI to change since suddenly elements beneath receive the event b) you will never receive an event in javascript for this element at all. This is different than receiving the event and then deciding to prevent the default action.

Comment: @jantimon I think I can try something else too, give me some time :)

Comment: @jantimon one thing I can think of is to add a `class` to the label on `mousedown` and on `mouseup` remove the class.. in the CSS, you can write the same class with `:active` pseudo and override the background color of the label

Comment: @jantimon something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/wp46heak/ not that great JS, but if you like the idea, I'll make it better and add it to my answer

Comment: Wow you are quite creative :) unfortunately I don't know the exact styles as they are added by a third party plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can disable mouse events via css.  Adding this CSS will will prevent the background from turning orange.

```css
label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you don't want to do it in every case, use a class and apply the `noclick` class only when needed (ie, as part react's render() method, or when the page is generated, depending on the framework you're using.

```css
.noclick {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Why adding a duplicate answer and then even using poor formatting?

Comment: @Christoph - The difference is with respect to managing state.  I don't know what your underlying technolology stack is, but binding to DOM events and directly manipulating the DOM is generally avoided if in unidirectional data flow paradigms, such as react/redux

Comment: I have no idea how your reaction is actually related to what I tried to say in my comment... :-)